# What's the right way to enable the node debugger with mocha's --debug-brk switch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, dom-events

I have some debugger statements in my module under test and want to run mocha with `--debug-brk` set and hit my breakpoint so that I can inspect the state of my module. Unfortunately, whenever I run mocha with this option, I end up with a blank cursor on the next line. I can enter text, but there's nothing that appears to be processing my commands (it certainly doesn't look like the node debugger):

```
$ mocha --debug-brk tests.js -R spec
debugger listening on port 5858
[BLANK CURSOR]
```

Am I doing something wrong with how I'm launching mocha?

Comment: Btw there is a difference between `--debug` and `--debug-brk`. The `--debug-brk` stops the application when it starts. The `--debug` starts the application and stops at your first breakpoint.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

To answer the original question, even though I also suggest you look into `node-inspector`: you can use the CLI debugger built into node through mocha with the `debug` option, instead of the `--debug` or `--debug-brk` *flags*. (Notice the lack of dashes.)

In your example, instead, it would be:

```
$ mocha debug tests.js -R spec
debugger listening on port 5858
connecting... ok
break in node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:7
  5  */
  6 
  7 var program = require('commander')
  8   , sprintf = require('util').format
  9   , path = require('path')
debug> [CURSOR]
```

Again, `debug` as above in bold, with no dashes. (=

Relevant: https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/issues/247

Comment: How come using `mocha debug` breaks in `node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha` instead of in my code where I put the `debugger` statement?  How do you get a REPL at the point in your code where you dropped the `debugger` statement?

Comment: this works (I had to `c` once to get to my breakpoint but NBD.)  What's annoying though is I can't seem to inspect anything when sitting at a breakpoint.  Like I can have `var foo='bar'; debugger;` and if I type `foo` at the prompt I get `ReferenceError: foo is not defined`

Comment: The *debugger* command-line is a JavaScript REPL, but it is *not* a REPL instantiated in the same environment as your code. (yes, this is confusing as hell, I know.) You have to remember to type `repl` at the debugger's command-line to get an actual interactive environment for your own code!

Comment: The `debug` argument got deprecated and replaced by `inspect` in mocha 7.0 https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/pull/3890

Answer (score 71):

**UPDATE**

[As of mocha 7.0.0](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/v7.0.0/CHANGELOG.md), `--debug-brk` has been removed in favor of `--inspect-brk`

---

Using a recent version of nodejs ([>=v6.3.0](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V6.md#2016-07-06-version-630-current-fishrock123)) and mocha ([>=3.1.0](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#310--2016-09-27)), you can use [V8 inspector integration](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_v8_inspector_integration_for_node_js).

> V8 Inspector integration allows attaching Chrome DevTools to Node.js
> instances for debugging and profiling

**Usage**

`--inspect` activates V8 inspector integration, and `--debug-brk` adds a breakpoint at the beginning. Since [nodejs v7.6.0](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V7.md#2017-02-21-version-760-current-italoacasas) and [mocha v3.3.0](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/releases/tag/v3.3.0), you can use the `--inspect-brk` shorthand for `--inspect --debug-brk`

```
$ mocha --debug-brk --inspect
Debugger listening on port 9229.
Warning: This is an experimental feature and could change at any time.
To start debugging, open the following URL in Chrome:
chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/serve_file/@62cd277117e6f8ec53e31b1be58290a6f7ab42ef/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=localhost:9229/node
```

**With npm scripts**

If you have a npm test script that uses mocha, you can pass the options from npm to your mocha script by using the *end of option delimiter* `--`:

`$ npm test -- --inspect --debug-brk`

**Chrome tip**

Instead of copy-pasting the url each time, go to `chrome://inspect` and click the appropriate link in the "Remote target" section.

Comment: The most useful answer in the end of 2016

Comment: I agree Kiril -- works great with the newer versions of Node. Was trying to use `node --inspect --debug-brk <my mocha command>` and it wasn't seeing the debuggers in my test cases. Switching to `<my mocha command> --inspect --debug-brk` solved that real quick! Thanks stropitek.

Comment: note this is supported as of [mocha v3.1.0](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#310--2016-09-27)

Comment: Thanks @busticated. I've added this to the answer, as well as the version of nodejs needed for v8 inspector integration

Comment: @stropitek - This helps a lot, thanks!  However, I am unable to set breakpoints - at least when running mocha in debugger with --watch.  Possibly because the sources are reloaded (unloaded?) for each iteration, chrome disables the breakpoint after the run is completed.  Do we have to sneak in a `debugger` statement and then insert breakpoints for each iteration?

Comment: @JørgenTvedt I gave it a try but I haven't been able to make `--inspect` and `--watch` work together.

Comment: for some reason `npm test -- --inspect --debug-brk` didn't work for me but `mocha ./test --debug-brk --inspect` did... anyone know why that might be?

Comment: @majorBummer difficult to say without further information but maybe you didn't configure a npm test script? https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Comment: `npm test -- --inspect --debug-brk` for nodev6.3+ is absolutely correct, I had started to doubt it but as @busticated pointed out, you need to upgrade mocha versions. In my case i went from `3.0.2` to `3.5.0`

Comment: I was able to get it work, wow -- tough experience debugging this!

Comment: As of 7.0.0 / 2020-01-05, this is deprecated in favor of `inspect`, refs https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/v7.0.0/CHANGELOG.md and https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/pull/3890

Answer (score 51):

I was able to get this to work using [node-inspector](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector). I run my test like you show in one shell:

```
mocha --debug-brk mocha/test.js
```

and then run node-inspector in a second shell:

```
node-inspector
```

Bringing up the URL that node-inspector spits out in a browser allows me to debug with the web inspector.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858
```

Comment: thanks - was hoping to just use Node's native interactive debugger, but it seems like node-inspector is the direction most folks have gone.

Comment: I did this and the debugger started on the first line of mocha source code.  I couldn't find a way to open my test and put a breakpoint there. How do I step into my test code conveniently?

Comment: @MedicineMan Add the line `debugger;` in your code wherever you want a break point. More info here: http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html

Answer (score 10):

If you have node-insector installed you can debug you Mocha tests without actually running node-inspector first. The easiest way is to

```
node-debug _mocha
```

That should start debugging the node tests in chrome (also works on Safari)

One reason I have seen that the tests do not work is sometimes you gave to try http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858 or http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858

Comment: This is the simplest answer for most people.

Comment: If you are also using Babel, [the `babel-node-debug` package/command](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-node-debug) might be helpful.

Comment: you may want to run "node-debug _mocha --no-timeouts" to ensure that timeout doesn't happen if you break in a test.

Answer (score 5):

run mocha with flag `--inspect-brk` and click 'open dedicated DevTools for node' in chrome from page `chrome://inspect`. In dedicated DevTools window add connection `localhost:9229` to connect automatically.

Also add a `debugger` statement to the file you want debug.

(this is using latest versions of node and chrome as of October 2017)