# Debugging mocha tests in IntelliJ: doesn't stop on breakpoints

Tags: javascript, debugging, intellij-idea, mocha.js

I'm trying to debug my Mocha test in IntelliJ 13.1.4 so I put breakpoints in my `test/test.js` file.

In my `Node.js` `Run/Debug Configurations`, I've correctly set the `Node interpreter` and the `Working directory` points to my project root.

The `JavaScript file` to execute is set to `./node_modules/.bin/mocha`.

If I click on the "Debug" button, my test is executed, but my breakpoints are ignored.

Does someone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it seems to be more a Mocha problem.

Here is what I did thanks to [that other similar SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14586655/535203): adding `--debug-brk` to the `Application parameters` in the `Run/Debug Configuration`.

Comment: Interesting...  Intellij adds that as part of the launch (in version 15 at least), but it assigns a port to it.  I added this as a parameter to the run configuration (without a port), and it worked.

Check it out: /.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/bin/node --debug-brk=50449 --nolazy node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha automation/wdio/**/*.test.js --reporter spec --debug-brk.

Adding the extra --debug-brk to the application parameters worked.

Comment: now it's probably --inspect-brk