# Warning about calling setState on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

The warning:

```
Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the _class component.
```

Any idea where it can come from. Gotchas or things like that ?

I already looked at all the setState in my code and replaced them to make sure. Can't find where it comes from...

My observations so far:

- Only happens in my tests
- No problem in the browser
- I thought I had more... but with more testing I got all confuse because it didn't fit the patterns I thought I understood...

So ! I understand what the error is but this time the warning is about a `_class component` so I'm lost... I just upgraded to `react-router` v4  and it needed a lot of changes so it's hard to localize the source of the warning.

Anyone had had a similar problem before ?

EDIT:
I found the `setState` that were causing problem. It was in `react-router-server`. I'll look into it to see if I can fix it !

Thanks @zerkms for the idea to look with a debugger to get the line number since there was no trace in the terminal.

I used the v8 experimental inspector(https://stackoverflow.com/a/39901169/3687661). Works pretty good :)

Answer (score 14):

This is common due to async activities like API calls. For example, this happen when you try to set a state after you receive the data from the server and the corresponding page to receive that state is not mounted.

To avoid this, check if the component is mounted before setting state in that component. Use a flag to check, say `this.mounted = true` in `componentDidMount` and change the flag to false in `componentWillUnmount`. Use `this.mounted` across the component to check if the component is mounted. This will fix the warning.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer :) You can maybe add this link too for other people: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

Answer (score 12):

This usually happens when you call `this.setState` within a `setTimeout` or `setInterval` or some other deferred function.

If you are using `setTimeout`/`setInterval` make sure you call `clearTimeout`/`clearInterval` in `componentWillUnmount`.

Comment: I thought about that,  I really looked all my `setState`'s. I don't have many. And after searching the code base, I have no setTimer nor setInterval. And the last times I had that warning, there was the name of the faulty component instead of `_class` so is it possible it's something with a library or the transpiler maybe ? Google is pretty quiet about it :P

Comment: @Yormi put a breakpoint on a line that emits that warning and you'd get a stack trace that points exactly to the malicious call.

Comment: A bit embarrassing, I'm not used to debugging in js with anything else than console.log... I don't have the line number with the warning in my terminal and it doesn't show up when I run the app in the browser. What is the easiest way to achieve that ? `iron-node` ? Btw, thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Yormi in the right part of the error message in the google chrome console there is a clickable file name + line number. You click on it then the exact place of the warning is show, and you put a breakpoint by clicking on the line number on the left. Then you refresh the page (or whatever you do to get that warning) and the debugger stops at that very line.

Comment: I manage to do it with the v8 node inspector as I wrote in the edit of the first post. But is there another way to start mocha's tests in the browser ?