# what is the logic of using an array to keep track of multiple setTimeouts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

I was just going through the code of react-slick and came across the following peice of code:-

```
this.callbackTimers.push(
     setTimeout(() => this.setState({ animating }), 10)
);
```

In the componentWillUnmount the callbackTimers are cleared like so :-

```
componentWillUnmount = () => {
    if (this.callbackTimers.length) {
      this.callbackTimers.forEach(timer => clearTimeout(timer));
      this.callbackTimers = [];
    }
};
```

Is the sole purpose of using the array to free memory or is there something that i have missed here ?

Why not just call the setTimeout directly:

```
setTimeout(() => this.setState({ animating }), 10)
```

instead of using an array ? i do see `callbackTimers` being used elsewhere too , but i don't know why exactly this array is needed apart from freeing memory, Is there any other purpose to this array ?

The line in question can be found [HERE](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/blob/master/src/inner-slider.js#L413).

Comment: Any timers that aren't expired yet are cleared so they don't trigger after the component has unmounted. Keeping references to them in an array is just the simplest way to do that.

Comment: @Alexander Solonik, setTimeout returns timer id which we can use for clearTimeout for preventing memory leak or as Chris mention for preventing the code to run after unmounting of the component.

Comment: Have you ever run into calling `setState` on an unmounted component?

Comment: @FelixKling not really no , i beleive not having the array and clearing it could cause that ?

Comment: @PulkitAggarwal makes sense thanks ..

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik with reference to what Felix mentioned, consider a case where a component makes a HTTP request but for some reason component unmounts before that request is completed, in this case, you will get [this warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40295315/warning-about-calling-setstate-on-an-unmounted-component)

Comment: @Yousaf makes perfect sense, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clearTimeout()` function is only necessary to cancel any pending timers. Otherwise, you don't really need to call `clearTimeout()` function to clear the memory.

In the code in your question, timers are cleared in the `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle method to cancel any pending timers when component is about to unmount. This will prevent any code in the callback function of any pending timer, from executing once the component has unmounted.