# In debug mode, mocha doesn't stop on debugger statements in a spec file when using node-inspector

Tags: node.js, debugging, mocha.js, node-inspector

When I run mocha with --debug-brk and open chrome dev tools with node-inspector, the debugger skips over any debugger statements that I put in my specfile.

I *can* get debugger statements to work in module files provided I follow [this trick](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/issues/247#issuecomment-11811089) of placing a breakpoint at the bottom of the mocha lib.

Has anybody else seen this problem?

Comment: What version of node-inspector are you using?

Comment: @MiroslavBajtoš 0.2.0beta4

Answer (score 2):

It seems that everybody should be seeing the same problem with node-inspector version 0.2.0beta4.

The problem is in the way how breakpoints are managed:

- The front-end remembers break-points in browser's local storage and restores them after the relevant file is loaded.
- When you start mocha with `--debug-brk` and stop on the first line, your specfiles are not loaded yet, so the front-end does not restore your breakpoints.
- When you resume mocha execution, front-end can't restore breakpoints quickly enough in the short window between a specfile is parsed and run. In fact mocha may exit before the V8 debugger has a change to notify front-end about new scripts being parsed!

Another workaround for this issue is to add `debugger;` statement in the specfile where you want to trigger a breakpoint.

**EDIT**

Note that the solution mentioned in node-inspector issue on github will work if you set breakpoint inside your `it` callback (i.e. spec implementation) but it won't help you with setting a breakpoint in the code which builds spec description (i.e. top-level code in your specfile and all `describe` callbacks).

Example:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var calculator = require('./StringCalculator');

// CANNOT break on the line below
describe('add', function() {
  // CANNOT break on the line below
  it('returns 0 for empty string', function() {
    // CAN break on the line below
    expect(calculator.add('')).to.equal(0);
  });
});
```

**EDIT2**

The problem is fixed in my fork of node-inspector: https://github.com/strongloop/node-inspector. You can set breakpoints anywhere in your specfiles immediately after the node-inspector UI is loaded in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29351654/3304034 for a decent enough work around